# Haskell - what type declaration would I use for this function?

Tags: haskell

What would the type declaration be for this Haskell function definition?

```
guessMe1 x y z | x == y = x + z
               | y == z = y + z
               | otherwise = x + y + z
```

Comment: Please, show what you tried to solve your problem and where you got stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can let this task to Haskell compiler like this:

```
ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :{
Prelude| guessMe1 x y z | x == y = x + z
Prelude|                | y == z = y + z
Prelude|                | otherwise = x + y + z
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :type guessMe1
guessMe1 :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a -> a -> a
Prelude>
```

The most usefull command is `:?`.
Then you can see:

```
...
:{\n ..lines.. \n:}\n       multiline command
...
:type <expr>                show the type of <expr>
...
```

Answer is:

```
guessMe1 :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> a -> a -> a
```

This means that the first second and third parameters must have a defined [equivalence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq) and must  be a [number](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num). Both the parameters and the result must have the same type.